# IBAction on button won't be called in custom keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, ibaction, custom-keyboard

I am making a custom keyboard that has a search bar. In order for a user to be able to interact with it, they must be able to:

1- Input text with individual letter buttons.

2- Tap the search button.

As for number 1, I have working IBActions that are called at every button press. For example, here's the action for the letter "m":

```
@IBAction func mPressed(button: UIButton) {
    searchBar.text! += "m"
}
```

However, the search button IBAction will not call:

```
@IBAction func searchPressed(button: UIButton) {
    print("searchPressed")
}
```

When I connect the search button in storyboard to the "mPressed" action, that action is called. But when I reconnect it back to the "searchPressed" function above, it doesn't work again.

I have also made sure that I correctly connected the button to the action.

[The search action is connected to the search button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Pvkn.png)

[The 'm' action is connected to the 'm' button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FkPV.png)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your screenshot search button connected to method `searchButtonPressed`, but in code you have method `searchPressed`.
Delete connection to `searchButtonPressed` and reconnect to `searchPressed` and it will work.

Comment: Thanks a lot , but unfortunately that didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Try to delete searchPressed method in code, then ctrl-drag and drop search button from IB to code to let XCode to create this method again.

Comment: Check in IB Attribute Inspector is Behavior -> Enabled checked.

Comment: As variant, add new button and connect to code. If it will work, configure it and replace with it old button

Comment: Turns out the print statements weren't working, so it led me to the wrong error. The action was being called, its just the logic in the function within the action wasn't exactly right so I couldn't tell. Thanks so much for the advice.

Comment: So, in your `func searchPressed` was another code, not `print("searchPressed")`?

Comment: I did have `print("searchPressed")` in the searchPressed IBAction, it just wasn't printing. But oddly enough everything else in the IBAction was working. But like I said the function being called in the Action had incorrect logic which, like the print statement not working, also made me think the problem was in the IBAction, when really it was in the function.  So now its working as it should.

Comment: in's strange, why `print("searchPressed")` didn't work... But, ok, finally you decide a problem.